# GetBytes() method returns different array for seemingly same strings

Tags: c#, arrays, .net

I've got two strings - one is retrieved from the DB and the other is scraped from the web - the two are then compared to check if there's been a change.

The issue is that both strings are seemingly identical, here:
`https://m.atcdn.co.uk/a/media/w267h200pdfdfdf/25bc7a46fdb6499db28370ab693f230c.jpg`
`https://m.atcdn.co.uk/a/media/w267h200pdfdfdf/25bc7a46fdb6499db28370ab693f230c.jpg`

However, when I use `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes()` on each string, they both return two different byte arrays.

What could be causing this?

Comment: They are the same string, and they produce equal byte arrays (at least, the strings posted to SO are identical): https://dotnetfiddle.net/IGnUEf. If that same code returns "False" for you, with your strings, please post the resulting byte arrays here. There might be some invisible characters in one of them, which are removed by SO.

Comment: Convert each byte array back to a string. Are the strings still identical?

Comment: How are the arrays different?

Comment: Are you perhaps inadvertently using a reference comparison of two arrays rather than comparing the bytes inside the arrays?

Comment: @RaymondChen I'm comparing the actual arrays generated for both strings - and they came out different.

Comment: @Azhari please edit your question to include the code you used to compare the two arrays

Comment: And ideally the content of the arrays, as bytes, too.

Comment: @KennethK. so I'm comparing the following strings:
https://m.atcdn.co.uk/a/media/w267h200pdfdfdf/b1f9a6d09c6d40b49e9e93474f775052.jpg
https://m.atcdn.co.uk/a/media/w267h200pdfdfdf/b1f9a6d09c6d40b49e9e93474f775052.jpg

and when i revert back to string i get these:
https://m.atcdn.co.uk/a/media/w267h200pdfdfdf/efb2eb0ecca94d1bb4dd96be5c1e4ece.jpg
https://m.atcdn.co.uk/a/media/w267h200pdfdfdf/b1f9a6d09c6d40b49e9e93474f775052.jpg

Comment: @KennethK. the weird thing is, they're both the same content - I'm honestly confused now

Comment: Please share your actual code that calls `GetBytes` on the two strings and then compares the bytes. Preferably something that can be pasted into dotnetfiddle and run directly.

Comment: If you plug those 2 different URLs into a browser they return the same picture. Sounds like the issue is elsewhere.

Comment: Manually convert the bytes into their character values (e.g. on paper, using an online chart/table). You should be able to see what the variant characters are. If there are any non-printable characters in the string, then you will see that when you convert the values.

Answer (score 3):

The strings you posted are indeed identical, so I think the issue lies somewhere else.

I can think of two possible causes:

1. You are not comparing the two Arrays the correct way and therefor they appear unequal to you.

   ```
   var bytes1 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("https://m.atcdn.co.uk/a/media/w267h200pdfdfdf/25bc7a46fdb6499db28370ab693f230c.jpg");
   var bytes2 = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("https://m.atcdn.co.uk/a/media/w267h200pdfdfdf/25bc7a46fdb6499db28370ab693f230c.jpg");

   // This will only compare the Reference of both Arrays, not their content:
   var equals = bytes1.Equals(bytes2); // bytes1 == bytes2;

   // Compare them like this instead:
   var equals = bytes1.SequenceEqual(bytes2);
   ```
2. If you receive the strings from an API or some third party, there might be additional characters like `\0` included, that are not visible to the user, but would affect the byte Array.

These are the only two reasons i can think of with the information you've given us.

Comment: SequenceEqual is indeed what I am using :\

Comment: @Azhari could you please update your original question with the code your using. Maybe we're able to spot something.

Comment: I'm literally using the same code as you have posted.

Comment: @Azhari if you did exactly what I did, it would work... Where are your strings coming from, are they input by a user?